# How to enable InnoDB storage engine for Mysql in Linux

Tags: linux, mysql, innodb

When I run the query "Show Engines" on this particular Linux host, it shows that the InnoDB storage engine is Disabled.  Other storage engines (like MyISAM) are showing enabled.

What steps would I need to take to install/enable the InnoDB storage engine (even at a high level)?  Would the procedures be different for different flavors of linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB can be enabled/disabled in your my.cnf (MySQL config), but, in order to use it MySQL has to have been compiled with InnoDB support.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it isn't disabled at compile time (as it normally isn't) but failed to start up. Check mysql's error log. Probably couldn't write the needed ibdata files..